# Are there any potential problems with having a single method to async webservice responses?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I have a Silverlight client application that communicated with a WCF web service for all sorts of things. All of the returns from these web services are inherited from a base ResponseObject. I have several methods to handle the async calls, one for each method call, with the appropriate handler added. I'm thinking now, wouldn't it be easier just to have a single method for all responses, and then have a switch statement that casts my response object accordingly. I generally don't have big methods to handle returns, just things like populating a combobox, etc.

Is there a reason why doing it this way would be bad? I send around so many small data requests, sometimes it seems like I spend half my time writing those response methods, even if they are trivial to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Could you write a T4 template that generates these methods for you? You could read in the WSDL  of the web service to see what methods need to be generated.